# Comparing database fields/columns with each other inside validations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following model in Rails which manages a Diabetes Settings table:

```
class DiabetesSetting < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    validates :bs_min, :bs_max, :bs_target, :correction_number, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :correction_insulin, numericality: true
    validates :bs_min {less_than: :bs_max }
    validates :bs_max {greater_than: :bs_min}
    validates :bs_target {less_than: :bs_max}

end
```

My Question: Is something like this, to compare the fields of a database  with each other to validate, that when a new setting is created, one value is higher or lower than the other, possible in Rails or do I have to write custom validation methods for this?

To clarify: bs_min is the mimmum value of a numerical range and bs_max the max value of a numerical range. They are both attributes inside the diabetes settings model. 
The Question is if I can compare these values like I did or if I have to write custom methods to validate

Thanks in advance for Your help

Comment: Can you describe more details about what actually you want to validate?

Comment: @Tai sure. I updated the Question. The main question is , though is it possible to validate the way I did or do I have to write custom validation methods? Thank You :-)

Comment: you'll have to do custom validators

Comment: @Anthony Shit, I thought so ;-) Would have been to good to be true if it would work the way I wrote it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Rail's built-in validations. Try below code:

```
class DiabetesSetting < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  validates_numericality_of :bs_min,    { less_than: :bs_max }
  validates_numericality_of :bs_max,    { greater_than: :bs_min }
  validates_numericality_of :bs_target, { less_than: :bs_max }
end
```

Refer to following link for numerical validation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of

Comment: Have you tried it? Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Rails 5.0.0. Validate it in Rails console.

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort but this is not working. When testing the model with unit tests and and setting up a valid instance of the model, the test fails.

Comment: @Anthony was right. When comparing data fielsd with each other inside validations you need to write custom validators.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails 7.0 added support for [`validates_comparison_of`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#comparison)   validations like this

```
validates :bs_min, comparison: { less_than: :bs_max }
validates :bs_max, comparison: { greater_than: :bs_min }
validates :bs_target, comparison: { less_than: :bs_max }
```